# Why can't I have a method in a generic class that takes parameters of a different generic type?

Tags: c#, generics

Like if for instance I have this class:

```
public class Result<T>
{
}
```

and I want to add a method like:

```
public class Result<T>
{
    void DoStuff(Result<T2> otherResult)
    {
        if (otherResult.HasErrors)
            DoWhatever();
    }
}
```

That's an error in C#, but I don't understand why. As long as I don't do anything with the other Result's T, why would the compiler mind?

Comment: You haven't defined T2 anywhere. What exactly is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you haven't declared `T2` anywhere.  You can do this:

```
void DoStuff<T2>(Result<T2> otherResult)
{

}
```